# How retrieve the Spring ApplicationContext through TestRule

Tags: spring, junit, spring-test

I want to know if is possible retrieve the `ApplicationContext` through a `TestRule`.

Here `TestRule` is used how an approach to avoid hierarchy among *Test Classes*, it with the purpose to reuse infrastructure configuration **but** in this case the structure needed are `@Beans` already created by Spring.

To keep simple the code to share, lets suppose we need retrieve the `Environment` object.

I have tried these two approaches:

**One**

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes={RootApplicationContext.class, ServletApplicationContext.class})
public class ManolitoRule implements TestRule {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ManolitoRule.class.getSimpleName());

    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {

        if(environment == null) {
            logger.error("NULL");
        }
        else {
            logger.info("Profiles: {}", Arrays.toString(environment.getActiveProfiles()));
        }

        return new Statement() {

                //The @Before configuration should go here now
                ...


            }


        };


    }

}
```

And

```
public class ManolitoTest {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ManolitoTest.class.getSimpleName());

    @Rule
    public ManolitoRule manolitoRule = new ManolitoRule();

    @Test
    public void manolitoTest() {

        ...

    }

}
```

The `environment` is `null`

**Two**

```
public class ManolitoRule implements TestRule {

    private final Environment environment;

    public ManolitoRule(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ManolitoRule.class.getSimpleName());

    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {

        if(environment == null) {
            logger.error("NULL");
        }
        else {
            logger.info("Profiles: {}", Arrays.toString(environment.getActiveProfiles()));
        }

        return new Statement() {

            //The @Before configuration should go here now    
            ....


        };


    }

}
```

And

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes={RootApplicationContext.class, ServletApplicationContext.class})
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners={LoggingTestExecutionListener.class}, mergeMode=MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
public class ManolitoTest {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ManolitoTest.class.getSimpleName());

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Rule
    public ManolitoRule manolitoRule = new ManolitoRule(environment);

    @Test
    public void manolitoTest() {

        ...

    }

}
```

Again the `environment` is `null`

Does exist a correct configuration to accomplish this configuration?

I have the impression that the life cycles between `JUnit` and `Spring Framework` are the reason of this situation.

**Note**: If an abstract class is used all work fine. But consider the scenario to avoid hierarchy and *chain* `@Rule`s, such as `ManolitoRule` working with `SpringClassRule` and `SpringMethodRule`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach **Two** is close to a working solution and just needs the following changes.

1. Annotate the test class with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`.
2. Configure an instance of `ManolitoRule` as a bean in the test's `ApplicationContext`.
3. Annotate the `ManolitoRule` constructor with `@Autowired`.
4. Annotate the `manolitoRule` field in the test class with `@Rule` *and* `@Autowired`.

Note: this technique does *not* work in conjunction with the Spring rules (`SpringClassRule` and `SpringMethodRule`). This technique only works in conjunction with the `SpringRunner`.

Comment: Thanks, seems something similar than https://blog.jayway.com/2014/12/07/junit-rule-spring-caches/

Comment: If you could share some snippet code for 2,3,4 would be valuable for a better understanding.

Comment: Yes, it is the exact same approach explained in that blog.

Comment: For steps 3 and 4, simply follow the guidelines in that blog.

Comment: For step 2, it's up to you how you define the bean, but the process is no different than for any other bean. Either configure it via an `@Bean` method in an `@Configuration` class; have it picked up via component scanning; or declare the class reference in `@ContextConfiguration(classes=...)`.

Comment: Interesting the `@Bean` and `@ContextConfiguration(classes=...)` approaches, I have declared the bean how a `@Component` and is scanned and works fine, it because in the blog use a `@Service` instead ... Of course I will test your suggestion too. Perhaps it could be the reason why my custom `@Rule` does not work together with `SpringClassRule` (with or without `RuleChain`) worst for `SpringMethodRule` because it does not implement `TestRule`

Comment: You can **not** use this technique with the Spring Rules! You can only use this technique with the `SpringRunner`. I have added a "Note" to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this confirmation, but the situation is that I normally use `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`  + `SpringClassRule` + `SpringMethodRule`. I already did a research about work with `SpringClassRule` + `SpringMethodRule` and a custom `@Rule` and not results, OK, you are saying is not possible.  Perhaps other approach to accomplish this? Perhaps would be possible in `JUnit` 5?. I would create a new Post question for this now...

Comment: Just in case for the community. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49238290/how-configure-correctly-runwithparameterized-class-springclassrule-spring

Comment: Yeah, it should be easier with JUnit Jupiter (i.e., JUnit 5). I'll mention that on the linked SO question as well.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to

```
@Autowired 
private Environment env;
```

**Edit:**
Try add this as well

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

Comment: Even when `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` has been added, it remains returning `null` for the two approaches.