# How configure correctly @RunWith(Parameterized.class) + SpringClassRule + SpringMethodRule with a custom @Rule?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test, junit5

I am working with `Spring Framework` 4.3.x and `JUnit` 4, I have the following structure

```
@Transactional
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={RootApplicationContext.class, ServletApplicationContext.class})
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners={LoggingTestExecutionListener.class}, mergeMode=MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
public class CompleteTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();
```

Thus the combination of:

- `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` + `SpringClassRule` + `SpringMethodRule`

works how is expected.

I have created a custom `TestRule` through `ExternalResource` as follows:

```
@Component
public class CompleteRule extends ExternalResource {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CompleteRule.class.getSimpleName());

    private final WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    private final Environment environment;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    public CompleteRule(WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext, Environment environment) {
        this.webApplicationContext = webApplicationContext;
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
      ...
    }
```

Thus If I try then use:

```
@Transactional
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={RootApplicationContext.class, ServletApplicationContext.class})
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners={LoggingTestExecutionListener.class}, mergeMode=MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
public class CompleteTest {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CompleteTest.class.getSimpleName());

    @Rule
    @Autowired
    public CompleteRule completeRule;

    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();
```

The `CompleteRule` is always ignored, it means the `ExternalResource.before` method overridden
by `CompleteRule` is never executed.

I have tried use

```
@Rule
public TestRule chain = RuleChain.outerRule(SPRING_CLASS_RULE)
                                                .around(completeRule);
```

And does not work. Even worst is not possible add `SpringMethodRule` because it implements `MethodRule` and not `TestRule` how the `around` method asks for.

I want avoid use `hierarchy` and work around with `Rules` instead. It because is a best practice.

Thus: Is there an approach to work around this?

**Note** I found in other post how a suggestion create `@Rule` and nest other Rules. Sadly no samples about this approach to test it.

**Note** is very important work around `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` because is mandatory use `@Parameters(name="{index}: ''{0}''")`
and `SpringClassRule` and `SpringMethodRule` are designed for this according with their API.

- [SpringClassRule](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/rules/SpringClassRule.html)
- [SpringMethodRule](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/rules/SpringMethodRule.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### JUnit 4

*The scenario you are describing is actually covered in [SPR-15927](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15927).*

It is impossible to have a custom `TestRule` injected by Spring actually picked up as a *rule* by JUnit if Spring is also configured via rules (e.g., via `SpringClassRule` and `SpringMethodRule`).

The custom `TestRule` field will in fact be injected by Spring, but that's too late in the game.

In other words, by the time the Spring rules are used to perform dependency injection, the current `Runner` will not notice that the injected custom `TestRule` exists, since the field was previously `null` during the rule detection phase.

It's basically a "chicken and egg" problem, and there is no built-in workaround for JUnit 4.

However, you can achieve something similar by *asking* Spring to perform dependency injection on an existing rule, but that requires custom code. See [SPR-10252](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10252) for details.

### JUnit Jupiter (JUnit 5)

With JUnit Jupiter 5.1 this should actually be easier to accomplish. Namely, you can combine parameterized test support with Spring without any problems.

The trick with JUnit Jupiter is to make sure you register the `SpringExtension` at the class level (e.g., via `@ExtendWith`, `@SpringJUnitConfig`, or similar). Then you can use `@RegisterExtension` and `@Autowired` on a field to have a Spring-managed extension injected into the test instance *and* used by JUnit Jupiter.

Comment: Thanks by the valuable explanation, thus I am going to go with `JUnit` 5. Do you remember when I created an issue about JUnit 5 in Github? I have shared there some code about my own experiments about migration and for `"Parameterized"` was not necessary use `SpringClassRule` and `SpringMethodRule` anymore. Now if my memory does not fail me, TestRule does not exists anymore in JUnit 5.